# Springboot With Mongodb Error while using find*() query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am getting the following error:

> at com.aks.springStorage.SpringStorageApplication.main(SpringStorageApplication.java:22) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Field 'locale' is invalid in: { locale: "company" }' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Field 'locale' is invalid in: { locale: "company" }' on server localhost:27017

Strange thing is I am not using any variable like "locale" in company collection.  I am able to insert and able to get the count, but none of the findAll* are
 working, getting the same error.

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, String> {
    List<Company> findByName(String name);

    @Query("{'contact.address': ?0}")
    List<Company> findByAddress(String address);
}

@Document(collation = "company")
public class Company {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Product> products;
    private Contact contact;

    public Company(int id, String name, List<Product> products, Contact contact) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.products = products;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}

// Client code:      
//this is working fine
int count = (int) companyRepo.count();

// Failing Here
companies = companyRepo.findByName("yy");
```

Comment: collation="company" seems like typo

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha thanks! it was a typo error, I changed to collection. it worked.

Comment: The elusive "this question is a typo but should stay because it's an infuriatingly easy auto-complete typo" question!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
@Document(collation="company")
```

This looks like a typo and the cause of your issue. You try to set collection name, but instead of [`collection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document.html#collection--) you use [`collation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document.html#collation--) property: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/

The correct form of annotation would be:

```
@Document(collection = "company")
public class Company {
    // ...
}
```

Or simpler – since `value` is an alias for `collection`:

```
@Document("company")
public class Company {
    // ...
}
```

You can even completely omit collection name. In that case Spring will use class name as collection name:

```
@Document // name of collection wil be "company", as per class name
public class Company {
    // ...
}
```

The last example is why this was working for you with e.g. count queries, even though you did not provide collection name explicitly.

Comment: this is issue with intellij AutoSuggest :)

Comment: Helps a lot, facing the same issue

Answer (score 13):

This sometime happens when you miss annotated entity class with annotation @Document

- Wrong
  @Document(collation = "department")
- Right
  @Document(collection = "department")

Comment: Hahah, this is exactly what got me :D

Answer (score 6):

On my side i used `@Document(collection =  "products")` and worked.
Use `collection` instead of `collation` in  `@Document`.

Answer (score 0):

I use `@Document(collection = "main class/name of database or collection")` instead of collation and it works, for example `@Document(collection ="student")`

Answer (score 0):

change @Document(collation = "company")  to @Document(collection = "company")