# Get() method error 500, Internal Server Error while using SpringBoot and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

I am beginner in SpringBoot and MongoDB
i tried to use GET method for Finding all my Players in MongoDB.
my program works for all methods: PUT,POST,DELETE and GET("/{ID}) but it does not works for GET()
I cannot understand where i made mistake, or what is the problem because i tried so many ways such as: changing the order and put the Get() getAllPlayers after getPlayerByID or i used @Get("/"), for this i recived Error 405.
could you help me please?!
my playerController is:

```
package thesisMongoProject.controller;    

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import thesisMongoProject.Player;
import thesisMongoProject.Repository.PlayerRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/player")
public class PlayerController {
    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository repo;

    //Get All Players
    @GetMapping
    public List<Player> getAllPlayers() {
        return repo.findAll();

    }

    //Getting Player ID
    @GetMapping("/{nickname}")
    public Player getPlayerByID(@PathVariable String nickname){
        return repo.findById(nickname).get();
        }





    //Delete Players
    @DeleteMapping
    public String deleteAllPlayers(){
        repo.deleteAll();
        return "Deleted!";      
    }

    //Create Player
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createPlayer(@RequestBody Player player){

                repo.save(player);
                return ResponseEntity.status(201).body("Created!");


    }

    //Delete player By ID
    @DeleteMapping("/{nickname}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deletePlayerByID(@PathVariable String nickname){
        try {

            Player p = repo.findById(nickname).get();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(p);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(404).body("Not Found!");
        }
    }

    //Update Player By ID
    @PutMapping("/{nickname}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updatePlayerByID(
            @PathVariable("nickname")String nickname,
            @RequestBody Player player){

        try {
            player.setNickname(nickname);
            repo.save(player);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(player);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(404).body("Not Found!");
        }

    }   

}
```

Comment: Please add the error you get to the question.

Comment: {
    "timestamp": "2020-04-21T11:28:21.734+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Field 'locale' is invalid in: { locale: \"player\" }' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Field 'locale' is invalid in: { locale: \"player\" }' on server localhost:27017",

Comment: There is an error in your log, check it and add it. MIght need to re-run with `--debug` enabled.

Comment: could you pleas see my code in Gitub: https://github.com/saharsahbaa/MyPlayers.git. i did not understand where is this log which you pointed

Comment: The query to your mongodb is wrong, which means you have a setup issue with MongoDB. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532821/springboot-with-mongodb-error-while-using-find-query

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
Inside MongoDB, i have database which name is palayers and inside this, i have collection which name is playaer
my mistake was, instead of writing @Document(Collection = "players"), i wrote @Document(colletion = "players")
and becuase they seems more or less similar i did not pay attention at them.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Change the order of the methods in your Controller

```
//Getting Player ID
@GetMapping("/{nickname}")
....

//Get All Players
@GetMapping
...
```

Comment: I used this, @GetMapping(value="/"),  but nothing changed and i had this error:               
 405, "error": "Method Not Allowed"

Comment: no problem, In fact i tried so many ways, i changed the order but in both cases, with @Get("/") i have error 405, and with using just @Get() i have error 500. Nothing changed for me.

Comment: Changing the order won't matter. Spring will detect the proper one, ordering isn't important.

Comment: Really? Pls add a reference to the documentation so we all learn