# Second mongodb table gives empty result while the database has the inserted data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I follow spring boot mongodb tutorail on the official site to create employer class and table and it works fine.

Then, I created another class call account which I used exactly the same way to implement.
/api/account gives me Json file with empty data.

Enter : localhost:8000/api/
result:

```
{
"_links":{
"employer":{
 "href":  "url/api/employer"
 "templated": true 
}
"account":{
 "href": "url/api/account"
"templated":true
profile:{
href: "url/api/profile"
}
```

I entered  localhost/api/account
result:

```
{
"_embedded":{
"account" :[{}]
}
```

my mongo db - "account" collection has two document data  and both "employer" and "account" collection are under test database.

Comment: Can you share your repository code?

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply. I found a solution. I got it working by adding @Document("account") on top of Account class. It is confusing that the tutorial mention nothing about the second table requires additional identifier.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532821/springboot-with-mongodb-error-while-using-find-query